# Cannot put subscribed observable into collection as a string

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, collections, file-io

I am kind of new to typescript and javascript, and I am having a real hard time figuring out how collections and file io works. I am trying to get data from a json file, which that I am successful in although when I put it into a collection the collection does not have the data.

Here is the code:

In my service class:

```
  private configuration = "../../assets/Configurations/testConfiguration.json";

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  getBlogs(blog: string): Observable<IBlogPost[]> {
    return this.http.get<IBlogPost[]>(blog);
  }

  getConfigurations() {
    var configurationsData = [];
    this.http.get(this.configuration).subscribe(data => {
      configurationsData.push(data);
      console.log(data);
      // This will work and will print all the paths
    });

    //This will not work and will not print them, like if the collection is empty
    configurationsData.forEach(x => console.log(x));

    return configurationsData;
  }
```

Where I get my service class injected:

```
blogs: IBlogPost[] = [];

  private blogsPaths: string[] = [];

  errorMessage = "";

  constructor(private appUtilityService: AppUtilityServices) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    //This will not work, blogsPaths will not received the full collection as it should
    this.blogsPaths = this.appUtilityService.getConfigurations();



    this.blogsPaths.forEach(blogPath =>
      this.appUtilityService.getBlogs(blogPath).subscribe(
        b =>
          b.forEach(blog => {
            this.blogs.push(blog);
          }),
        error => (this.errorMessage = <any>error)
      )
    );
  }
```

testConfiguration.json:

```
[
  "../../assets/BlogPosts/testBlog1.json",
  "../../assets/BlogPosts/testBlog2.json"
]
```

Bonus if you include a good tutorial on how collections work in javascript and how to return them properly

Comment: Instead of using configurationsData.push(data); , maybe try Array.prototype.push.apply(configurationsData, data);

Comment: nope
jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
    at dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
    at q.handle (jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3)
dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3
load (async)  
add @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3
(anonymous) @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3
each @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2
each @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:2
ya @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3
on @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js:3
(anonymous) @ carousel.js:495
(anonymous) @ carousel.js:11
(anonymous) @ bootstrap.min.js:6

Comment: I didn't  see any jQuery code in your code. Why are you using jQuery with angular?

Comment: I am not, that's the error that comes up, probably because some code works with jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out to be this, yes really...

Here I made it nice:

OnInit:

```
this.appUtilityService.getConfigurations().subscribe(
  b =>
    b.forEach(x => {
      this.appUtilityService.getBlogs(x).subscribe(
        b =>
          b.forEach(blog => {
            this.blogs.push(blog);
          }),
        error => (this.errorMessage = <any>error)
      );
    }),
  error => (this.errorMessage = <any>error)
);
```

AppUtilityService:

```
  getBlogs(blog: string): Observable<IBlogPost[]> {
    return this.http.get<IBlogPost[]>(blog);
  }

  getConfigurations(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.http.get<string[]>(this.configuration);
  }
```

Make it really nice:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeBlog();
  }

  private initializeBlog(): void {
    this.appUtilityService.getConfigurations().subscribe(
      b =>
        b.forEach(x => {
          this.appUtilityService.getBlogs(x).subscribe(
            b =>
              b.forEach(blog => {
                this.blogs.push(blog);
              }),
            error => (this.errorMessage = <any>error)
          );
        }),
      error => (this.errorMessage = <any>error)
    );
  }
```

Comment: No problem ;-) Just wanted to give you another option. I understand that observables can be confusing at first glance, but your code will gain in readability with more powerful. Angular is natively designed with Observables and RxJS, and it's a real pleasure to use them, once adopted.

Answer (score 0):

Inside `getConfigurations`, you're invoking an asynchronous http request. So it's normal, that `configurationsData` is empty outside the `subscribe` method.

Here, I'm using the **powerful of RxJS** to simplify the code and avoid to use 
`Array.push` and nested `subscribe()`.

**1) Basic async service method to get data**

So `getConfigurations` should return an `Observable`:

```
getConfigurations(): Observable<string[]> {
  return this.http.get<string[]>(this.configuration);
}
```

And also `getBlogs` should return an `Observable`:

```
getBlogs(blogsPath: string): Observable<BlogPost[]> {
  return this.http.get<BlogPost[]>(blogsPath);
}
```

Here, to respect Angular best practice, I remove `I` at the beginning of each interface, so `BlogPost`.

**2) Here is the magic of RxJS**

Then, you have another method inside your service to retrieve an `Observable` of blog posts, which should look like this:

```
getBlogPosts(): Observable<BlogPost[]> {
  return this.getConfigurations().pipe(
    mergeAll(),
    concatMap(blogsPath => this.getBlogs(blogsPath)),
    concatAll(),
    toArray()
  )
}
```

Which means, retrieve all collection of blog paths, for each array of paths, for each path, get blog posts, and then return an unique array of all posts.

Finally, inside your component, you call `getBlogPosts` with a subscription:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.service.getBlogPosts().subscribe(blogs => {
    ...do something with your blogs array.
  });
}
```

or even better with `async` pipe inside your template :

.ts file:

```
blogs$: Observable<BlogPost[]>;
...
this.blogs$ = this.appService.getBlogPosts();
```

.html file:

```
<ul *ngIf="blogs$ | async as blogs">
    <li *ngFor="let blog of blogs">
        #{{ blog.id }} - {{ blog.title }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Check my [full demonstration of this RxJS alternative](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pxp2mb) on Stackbliz.

Recommended read on [medium from Tomas Trajan](https://blog.angularindepth.com/practical-rxjs-in-the-wild-requests-with-concatmap-vs-mergemap-vs-forkjoin-11e5b2efe293)

Comment: This does not work ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at HttpXsrfInterceptor.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpXsrfInterceptor.intercept (http.js:1814)
    at HttpInterceptorHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptorHandler.handle (http.js:1228)
    at HttpInterceptingHandler.push../node_modules/@angular/common/fesm5/http.js.HttpInterceptingHandler.handle (http.js:1865)
    at MergeMapSubscriber.project

Comment: I want to avoid making a type for configuration data, I just want to put in the strings showing from configuration a collection

Comment: You can use string[] or 'any' if you want (but type strongly recommended). Errors seems not related directly to code proposed. There is a problem with http request or http interceptor. Can you check please ? Are you using HttpClient ? or Http ?

Comment: constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
you cannot use string[] it takes a string as input param this.appUtilityService.getBlogs(blogPath)

Comment: ok, could you add `mergeAll()` in the pipe. I updated my answer. We need to flatten it into n string values emitted in the stream.

Comment: Nope it does not work, also mind that if you are passing blog, blog is not of type string, thus you have to change the method to take any

Comment: @BrainBytes I've just updated my answer to give more details and a full demonstration on stackblitz. I didn't change the core of my initial post. It avoids nested subscribe. which are correct, but less powerful than RxJS operators, and with less readability.

Comment: I am going to try your answer, although please read above, my answer seems much less complex and lengthy (but probably that's just me), although thank you for trying man, thank you for the stackblitz demo